# Installing docker in client mode

Tags: docker, centos, client, docker-machine

I have CentOS 5.11 and installed docker-machine on it. Using docker-machine, i created a docker host on AWS. I want to use my CentOS machine as a client to run commands on this host. How do i install docker in client mode on this machine.

Docker documentation says that docker can be installed in client mode which can run on any kernel. I don't see any instructions for installing it this way.(https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/binaries/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no client binary for Linux, this is just somewhat confusingly worded in the Docker docs imo.

The binary for Linux is client and server. So all you need to do is:

- download latest binary ( or whatever version you want, latest is probably the smart move though ) from https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/i386/docker-latest or https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest depending on your system
- chmod +x the downloaded file `chmod +x docker-latest`
- move it in your path, maybe just `sudo mv docker-latest /usr/local/bin/docker`

... that should be all you need to do to get client only Docker operation. No Docker daemon will start if you only do the above => client only :)

Comment: Followed the above steps. When you run any docker command like "docker -v", following error is seen "FATAL: kernel too old
Segmentation fault"

Comment: Well unfortunately that error is what is wrong then. You need to upgrade to a newer Kernel version.

Comment: "Note that Docker also has a client mode, which can run on virtually any Linux kernel (it even builds on OS X!)" - Looks like CentOS 5.11 doesn't qualify for the statement mentioned in docker docs.

Comment: Yea, I think any really is true more in the sense of "any recent" :/

Comment: The link above is invalid now, newest link is `https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest.tgz`, and also need extract the unarchive before move to path directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-17.06.2-ce.tgz
tar xvzf docker-17.06.2-ce.tgz
sudo mv docker/docker /usr/bin/docker
chmod +x /usr/bin/docker
docker version
rm -rf docker/
```

These commands will:

- download binaries for `linux` `x86_64`
- extract files
- move binary `docker` to `/usr/bin`
- make it executable
- test `docker`
- delete others files downloaded